# JQuery ajaxfileupload with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Good morning.

I wanna ask about JQuery ajax fileUpload. I have some issues regarding this.

1. I want to pass some variable from javascript function
2. Insert the variables and value from uploading file through jquery ajax

### Here are the javascript function :

```
var baseurl = 'http://fadli.com/';
            function upload_item(kode,field,table)
        {
            $("#upload_item_"+table+"_"+kode).hide(); //hide submit button
            $("#loading_image_upload_"+table+"_"+kode).show(); //show loading image
            console.log('masuk ke fungsi upload');


            $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url             : baseurl+"admin/level/upload_item/"+kode+"/"+field+"/"+table, 
                //url           :'./admin/level/upload_file/',
                secureuri       : false,
                fileElementId   :'userfile_'+table+'_'+field+'_'+kode,
                dataType        : 'json',
                data            : {
                    'title'             : $('#sub_modul_title_'+kode).val()
                },
                success : function (data, status)
                {
                    if(data.status != 'error')
                    {
                        // $('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
                        // refresh_files();
                        // $('#title').val('');
                        alert('sukses brow');
                        $("#upload_item_"+table+"_"+kode).show(); //show submit button
                        $("#loading_image_upload_"+table+"_"+kode).hide(); //hide loading image
                    }
                    console.log(data.msg);
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log(thrownError);
                    $("#upload_item_"+table+"_"+kode).show(); //show submit button
                    $("#loading_image_upload_"+table+"_"+kode).hide(); //hide loading image
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

### And here is the HTML code :

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile_sub_modul_sub_modul_id_<?php echo $sub->sub_modul_id?>" class="styled-finputs">
<button class="btn btn-labeled btn-success btn-xs" type="button" id="upload_item_sub_modul_<?php echo $sub->sub_modul_id; ?>" onclick="upload_item('<?php echo $sub->sub_modul_id?>','sub_modul_id','sub_modul')"><span class="btn-label icon fa fa-picture-o"></span> Upload gambar</button>                                                           
<img src="http://fadli.com/assets/img/input-spinner.gif" id="loading_image_upload_sub_modul_<?php echo $sub->sub_modul_id?>" style="display:none" />
```

The problem is after the first console log, it's not working all way down.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For ajaxFileUpload, it is starting with capital A, try to change `ajaxFileUpload` to `AjaxFileUpload`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply submit the form with ajax(without page reload).
Just use this code.It will submit your files data too.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)//I wrote it for any form.You can change it for specific form
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),//make sure your form has action url
        type: $(this).attr("method"),//Your form method type GET OR POST
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {


        }
    });
});
```

Also you can add addition data with `FormData`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects
You can modify the above function like this

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)
{
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append("MORE_INPUT_KEY", "MORE_DATA");
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),//set any link
        type: $(this).attr("method"),//set any metho
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: formData ,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {


        }
    });
});
```